# What is my word

Tags: riddle, word

***What is this word (I have put it in parts)?***


**The first part** is big, fat and found at the zoo
**The second part** may have been lurking beneath your childhood bed
**The third part** means the same as 6/4
**The fourth part** will be found on a bike
**The final part** is the word of fear


***If needed, I will give hints.***

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I fear posting this, but was reassured by M Oehm who found a better split:

> [hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia)

The first part is big, fat and found at the zoo

> hippopot(o)  clues **hippopotamus**

The second part may have been lurking beneath your childhood bed

> monstr(o)se  clues **monsters**

The third part means the same as 6/4

> [**sesqui**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sesqui) - 1½ times i.e. increased by 50% - thanks M Oehm.

The fourth part will be found on a bike

> pedal(io) clues **pedal**

The final part is the word of fear

> phobia

---

Original split-up with some missing parts and tenuous for the 6/4 part:

> hippo + pot + [o] + monstro + [sesqui] + pedal + [io] + phobia

Comment: Ha! Very likely the correct overall answer, but I think you've got a shift in your parts. If you use the full name for (1), you can use your (3) as (2) and the part you left out between (3) and (4) will now become your (3). Still, the whole answer will be a bit rough at the seams.

Comment: Thanks @MOehm especially for your 6/4 solution which is definitive.

Comment: Yes. M Oehm is correct.